# solid half sphere question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A solid half-ball $H$ of radius $a$ with density given by $k(2a-\rho)$, where $k$ is a constant. Find its mass.

You of course use spherical coordinates so $dV=\rho ^2 \sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta$. It is clear to see that the limits are $\rho \in [0,a]$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. The limits for $\phi$ are normally $[0,\pi]$ but it is apparently $[0,\pi/2]$ but I don't know how...

Is it because it is a half sphere? If so then why can't you half the limits for $\theta$ instead or why not half it for both of the angle variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you set your half ball above xy-plane.

Yes, the angle $\phi$ is from $0$ to $\pi/2$. That is because the angle $\phi$ is considered to be the angle from positive $z$-axis downward. It reaches $\pi/2$ at the xy-plane and will not go further, since it is a half-sphere.

The angle $\theta$ though is the angle going around $z$-axis in xy-plane. In this case, it goes through the whole circle.

See here for a picture: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html.

Answer (score 0):

Since everything is symmetric here, you could also compute the mass of the full ball and halve it.

Comment: You should probably expand a bit on this to make it a fully fleshed out answer.